# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'useEntityProp')

Tags: post-meta, block-editor

I'm working on a custom block and want to store some values in meta instead of the properties. So I followed the instructions from here [Meta Boxes | Block Editor Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/metabox/#step-2-add-meta-block) but after building the block and using them in the Editor I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'useEntityProp')
```

I couldn't find so far why it seems that `useEntityProp` is undefined.

My `package.json` contains the following dependencies:

```
"@wordpress/block-editor": "^12.9.0",
"@wordpress/blocks": "^12.18.0",
"@wordpress/components": "^25.7.0",
"@wordpress/core-data": "^6.18.0",
"@wordpress/data": "^9.11.0",
"@wordpress/dom-ready": "^3.41.0",
"@wordpress/element": "^5.18.0",
"@wordpress/scripts": "^26.6.0",
"@wordpress/server-side-render": "^4.18.0",
"postcss": "^8.4.24",
"postcss-scss": "^4.0.6"
```

Here is the actual code:

```
import {registerBlockType} from '@wordpress/blocks';
import {InspectorControls, useBlockProps, MediaUploadCheck, MediaUpload} from "@wordpress/block-editor";
import {useEntityProp} from "@wordpress/core-data";
import {useSelect} from "@wordpress/data";
import {Button, Disabled, PanelBody, RangeControl, SelectControl, TextControl} from '@wordpress/components';
import {ProjectHeader} from '../icons';
import './project-header.scss';

const ALLOWED_MEDIA_TYPES = ['image'];

export const Template = ({attributes}) => {
    const {image, title, contentWidth, labels, labelValues, subject} = attributes;
    const imageUrl = image ? image.url : '';
    const bgStyle = {
        backgroundImage: 'url(' + imageUrl + ')',
    };
    const contentStyle = {
        maxWidth: contentWidth + 'px'
    };

    return (
        <div className={'wp-block-bbc-project-header__image' + ' subject--' + subject} style={bgStyle}>
            <div className={'wp-block-bbc-project-header__content'} style={contentStyle}>
                <div className={'wp-block-bbc-project-header__back'}>
                    <button className={'button--back'} onClick={'history.back()'}></button>
                </div>
                <div className={'wp-block-bbc-project-header__labels'}>
                    {labelValues && Object.entries(labelValues).map(([key, label]) => (
                        <div key={key} className={`label`}>
                            {label}
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
                <div className={'wp-block-bbc-project-header__title'}>
                    <span>{title}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

registerBlockType('bbc/project-header', {
    apiVersion: 2,
    title: 'Projekt Header',
    icon: ProjectHeader,
    category: 'bbc',
    attributes: {
        title: {
            type: 'string',
            default: 'Titel'
        },
        contentWidth: {
            type: 'int',
            default: 1220
        },
        image: {
            type: 'object',
            selector: 'js-image',
        },
    },

    edit({ setAttributes, attributes }) {
        const blockProps = useBlockProps();
        const {image, title, contentWith} = attributes;
        const postType = useSelect(
            (select) => select('core/editor').getCurrentPostType(),
            []
        );

        const [meta, setMeta] = useEntityProp('postType', postType, 'meta');


        /** META FIELDS **/
        const labels = meta['_bbc_projects_labels'];
        const labelValues = meta['_bbc_projects_label_values'];
        const subject = meta['_bbc_projects_subject'];

        /** META UPDATE FUNCTIONS **/
        const updateLabels = (labels, options) => {
            setMeta({...meta, '_bbc_projects_labels': labels});
            let values = [];
            labels.labels.forEach((label) => {
                let item = options.find(item => parseInt(item.value) === parseInt(label));
                values.push(item.label)
            });
            setMeta({...meta, '_bbc_projects_label_values': values});
        }
        const updateSubject = (value) => {
            setMeta({...meta, '_bbc_projects_subject': value});
        };

        /** FETCH LABELS **/
        const {labelRecords} = useSelect((select) => {
            const {getEntityRecords} = select('core')

            return {
                labelRecords: getEntityRecords('postType', 'bbc-projects-label', {
                    status: 'publish',
                    orderby: 'title',
                    order: 'asc',
                    per_page: 100
                }),
            }
        })

        /** FETCH SUBJECT AREA **/
        const {subjectRecords} = useSelect((select) => {
            const {getEntityRecords} = select('core')

            return {
                subjectRecords: getEntityRecords('postType', 'bbc-projects-subject', {
                    status: 'publish',
                    orderby: 'title',
                    order: 'asc',
                    per_page: 100
                }),
            }
        })

        let labelOptions = []
        let subjectOptions = []
        if (labelRecords) {
            labelRecords.forEach((label) => {
                labelOptions.push({value: label.id, label: label.title.rendered})
            })
        } else {
            labelOptions.push({value: 0, label: 'Loading...'})
        }

        if (subjectRecords) {
            subjectRecords.forEach((label) => {
                subjectOptions.push({value: label.id, label: label.title.rendered})
            })
        } else {
            subjectOptions.push({value: 0, label: 'Loading...'})
        }
        return (
            <div {...blockProps}>
                <InspectorControls key="setting">
                    <PanelBody title="Einstellungen" initialOpen={true}>
                        <p>Bild</p>
                        <MediaUploadCheck>
                            <MediaUpload
                                title={'Bild (min.: 1440px x 505px)'}
                                className="js-image wp-admin-image"
                                allowedTypes={ALLOWED_MEDIA_TYPES}
                                multiple={false}
                                value={image ? image.id : ''}
                                onSelect={image => setAttributes({image: image})}
                                render={({open}) => (
                                    image ?
                                        <div>
                                            <p>
                                                <img src={image.url} width={image.width / 2} alt={''} />
                                            </p>
                                            <p>
                                                <Button onClick={() => setAttributes({image: ''})}
                                                        className="button is-small">Bild
                                                    entfernen</Button>
                                            </p>
                                        </div> :
                                        <Button onClick={open} className="button">Bild auswählen</Button>
                                )}
                            />
                        </MediaUploadCheck>
                        <RangeControl
                            label="Inhalt Breite in Pixel"
                            value={contentWith}
                            min={800}
                            max={2000}
                            step={10}
                            withInputField={true}
                            initialPosition={1220}
                            onChange={(value) => setAttributes({contentWidth: value})}
                        />
                        <TextControl
                            label="Titel"
                            value={title}
                            onChange={(value) => setAttributes({title: value})}
                        />
                        <SelectControl
                            label="Fachrichtung"
                            value={subject}
                            multiple={false}
                            options={subjectOptions}
                            onChange={updateSubject}
                        />
                        <SelectControl
                            label="Labels"
                            value={labels}
                            multiple={true}
                            options={labelOptions}
                            onChange={(value) => updateLabels({labels: value}, labelOptions)}
                        />
                    </PanelBody>
                </InspectorControls>
                <Disabled>
                    <Template attributes={attributes} />
                </Disabled>
            </div>
        );
    },
    save: (props) => {
        const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();
        const {attributes} = props;
        return (
            <div {...blockProps}>
                <Template attributes={attributes} />
            </div>
        );
    },
    example: {
        attributes: {
            preview: true,
        },
    },
});
```

Here ist the PHP to enqueue the Block.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Bbc\Projects;

use Bbc\Projects\PostType\ProjectLabelPostType;
use Bbc\Projects\PostType\ProjectPostType;
use Bbc\Projects\PostType\ProjectSubjectAreaPostType;

class Plugin
{
    private static ?self $instance = null;

    public static function init()
    {
        if (!self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }

        add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', [self::$instance, 'enqueueAssets']);
        add_action('enqueue_block_assets', [self::$instance, 'enqueueAssets']);

        ProjectPostType::init();
        ProjectSubjectAreaPostType::init();
        ProjectLabelPostType::init();
    }

    public function enqueueAssets()
    {
        $assetConfigFile = sprintf(
            '%s/build/main.asset.php',
            dirname(__DIR__)
        );
        $assetConfig = include $assetConfigFile;

        wp_enqueue_script(
            ProjectPostType::NAME,
            plugins_url('/build/main.js', __DIR__),
            [],
            $assetConfig['version']
        );

        wp_enqueue_style(
            ProjectPostType::NAME,
            plugins_url('/build/main.css', __DIR__),
            [],
            $assetConfig['version']
        );
    }
}
```

As it lead to questions, the Block works fine if I store everything in the props, but it failed when I wanted to store some of them in meta.

Comment: What's the actual code that's causing the problem?

Comment: @JacobPeattie i've added the code, hope it helps

Comment: note that you need at minimum WP 5.4 to use that, this is also assuming you generated your block with WP Scripts and are using the provided mechanism for registering and enqueing your block from PHP, is that the case? I mention this because you've used `registerBlockType` which isn't how that script sets things up right now, it's meant to create a `block.json` which is then ingested in PHP to register the block, and loaded in the build process for registering in JS, with all your attributes etc going in there, which isn't what we're seeing here.

Comment: because of that the problem may be as simple as not enqueing the blocks JS properly and adding the dependencies it needs to it loads in the wrong order. Can you update your question to show the PHP part?

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes, I'm currently using WP 6.3. I generated the block with WP Scripts and registered and enqueued my block from PHP.

Comment: @TomJNowell I've added the PHP Part. The Block works fine if I store everything in the Props, the issue happened after I tried to store some of them in Meta instead of the Props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That script uses lots of WordPress packages, and WP Scripts makes sure it doesn't put those in the built JS to stop it getting huge. Part of that is it creates a PHP file that just returns an array of all the things.

**That code however has put `[]` in the dependencies spot, and tells WordPress that the script has zero dependencies and can be loaded in *any* order. As a result it's loading *before* the `@wordpress/core-data` library and has no idea what `useEntityProps` means yet.**

The other stuff works because it's not running until your block is shown which happens later on. You might find that this error message looks different depending on the computer used, and the network conditions.

So to fix this, declare all the dependencies when it's enqueued, something WP Scripts would normally do for you out of the box ( and something it probably did but was deleted to make way for a namespaced class ). It's very likely WP Scripts is still set up to create a PHP file that lists all the dependencies on build to automate the process, if so include that file e.g. `$dependencies = include( ....` ( yes PHP files can return values just like functions, and `include` has return values too! )

Comment: Thank you Tom, it looks like the missing dependencies was the Problem. But now it looks like `meta` is undefined from `const [meta, setMeta] = useEntityProp('postType', postType, 'meta');`

Comment: Glad that worked for you, I’d suggest creating a new question for the meta problem though, I can only answer the question you wrote. If this solves your original problem consider marking it as the correct answer

Comment: Thank you, I simply forgot to add `custom-fields` support when adding the custom post type.